# Having trouble with ajax call and querying DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm very new to javascript and JQuery. I'm making a web application where I want to perform an ajax call on the front end, then on the backend I'm trying to query my database to get information to send to the front end.

Here is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({    type: "POST",
            url: "/offer/disable",
            data: {spaceId: spaceId},
        }).success(function(response, status) {

            unavailableDates = response.unavailableDates;
            console.log("received " + unavailableDates);

        }).fail(function(err, status){
            console.log("failure");

        });


  });
```

and here is my post method:

```
router.post('/disable', function(req, res, next) {

  console.log("disable post method was called");

    //get the dates that are unavailable
    Space.getSpaceById(res.body.spaceId, function(error, space){

        if(error)
            return error;

        console.log(space);
        console.log(space.unavailableDates);
        res.send({unavailableDates: space.unavailableDates});

    });


});
```

My ajax call is failing and my db is never being queried. My post method is being called though. I have no idea why this is happening or how to fix it.

Comment: .success -> .done (but this won't fix your problem)

Comment: Start by throwing the error, rather than returning it.

Comment: May also help to actually log some error information rather than "failure".

Comment: It is not even executing my space.getSpaceByID() method. "POST /offer/disable 500 6.943 ms - 6524" I am getting on my server side.

Comment: Status 500 -> Internal Server Error -> Something is wrong with your server code

Comment: just found my mistake! so stupid of me I was doing res.body instead of req. WOW. thanks everyone so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake-- was doing res.body instead of req.body.